# Is there a Visual Studio plugin for sorting build output (scrambled from multi-threaded builds)?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

My work just gave me a quad core computer, and WOW build times are fast! (What used to take 20+ minutes now takes 7 minutes).

Anyway, Visual Studio builds project in parallel (great for build times), but scrambles the output:

```
1>Performing Makefile project actions
3>arg.c
2>msg.c
3>log.c
4>test.c

(and so on....)
```

Is there a plugin that sorts the output when the build is complete?

Comment: How do I enable multi-threaded build?

Comment: It should be automatic is you have a multi-core computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Selecting the "Build order" item in the "Show output from" dropdown list in the output and errors panes probably does what you are looking for.

Comment: Doh!  I didn't even realize that was there!  Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: And is there a way to get the same when running devenv from command line with newer VS versions like VS2017 ?

Comment: @Epligam not that I know of - however, you could probably pipe the output to powershell and use `Sort-Object -Stable`