# Sort Visual Studio build log in "Build Order" style

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, build-process, build, build-automation

There is a "Show output from" dropdown list in Visual Studio 2008 "Output" window, which allows viewing build events ordered by thread ([Build Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192561/is-there-a-visual-studio-plugin-for-sorting-build-output-scrambled-from-multi-th)). This is very useful when building big solutions on multi-core machines, as the log entries from those come unsynchronized.

Our organization has the automated build process, where solution(s) are compiled in a batch mode, using something like:

```
devenv Solution.sln /USEENV /build Release /out buildlog.txt
```

This will load `Solution.sln`, buld it in `Release` configuration and output build log into `buildlog.txt`.

Problem is: `buildlog.txt` is an output resembling "Build" output, not "Build Order", and therefore, it is pretty hard to read. Is there a command-line filter or something, which would convert output to "Build Order" format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple filter, something like that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lines = new Dictionary<int, StringBuilder>();
    var line = Console.In.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        int process = 0;
        var re = new Regex(@"^(?<process>\d+)\>.*$");
        if (re.IsMatch(line))
        {
            var match = re.Match(line);
            process = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["process"].Value);
        }

        if (!lines.ContainsKey(process))
        {
            lines[process] = new StringBuilder();
        }
        lines[process].AppendLine(line);

        line = Console.In.ReadLine();
    }

    foreach (var i in lines.Keys)
    {
        Console.Write(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this will solve the formatting issue, but you could try using `msbuild` instead of `devenv`, with a command line such as:

`msbuild Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /logger:XMLLogger,C:\Loggers\MyLogger.dll;OutputAsHTML`

See the documentation for msbuild for information on the logging options. You may find that this will give you the ability to have a more sensible output.

Comment: I guess this method is a valid resolution, although I couldn't make msconfig to build solution when I ran it using following line: "MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:PlatformName=Win32 ", but once that's fixed, I guess, I could write custom logger to log properly. I would still like to see if there is a simpler resolution

Comment: Try: 
`msbuild Solution.sln /p:Configuration="Release|Win32" /target:"MainProject"`

Comment: Didn't work, but `MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=Win32` did. Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't MSBuild only build one project at a time? If yes, how will that help me with parallel builds?

Comment: I think msbuild may build in parallel. Visual Studio itself uses msbuild under the hood, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I ran msbuild it was only building one project at a time. I think Visual Studio spawns multiple MSBuilds

Comment: I think that may be correct -- maybe it's in VS2010 where msbuild is able to parallelise.

Comment: msbuild has the `/m` command-line switch to enable concurrent build processes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Walter's answer works for all the situation, because I've seen the problem when building C# projects and VS prints the Compile results withouth any process ID! such as

1>------ Build started: Project: MyProj, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

Compile complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings

Please note that I removed most of other outputs but imagine you're building a lot of projects and Compile complete line is not inserted right after the correct project, how would you find which project Compile complete belongs?

Comment: probably not, but at least it provides readable output. Since msbuild is single-threaded, using it is really nothing more that setting up visual studio to use 1 process at a time, and for that I don't need to do anything special, it can be done thruoptions