# How do I sort build output of Visual Studio by Build Order by default?

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2005, trace, output

I know that I could sort the build output of my multicore builds in Visual Studio using the **Build Order** item in the **Output** window (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192561/is-there-a-visual-studio-plugin-for-sorting-build-output-scrambled-from-multi-t)).

But once I've done that and hit <kbd>F7</kbd> again, the option switches back to **Build** and I have to switch back to **Build Order** again.

Is there a way to set **Build Order** as default setting in the **Output** window?

Searching a bit shows me that this question was asked several times but never answered:

- http://ntcoder.com/bab/2009/06/02/ordering-output-of-out-of-order-builds-in-visual-studio/#comment-484
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/07/03/show-the-output-window-during-build-vstiptool0045.aspx#comments
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/21/428094.aspx#1451451

---

**Edit:**
The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377496/520162) given by [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) works for me (or at least it points me to the right direction), but I could not simply copy his code and insert it in my `MyMacros` project. Instead, I have to create the handler for the build events **exactly** as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b27f9kz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> 1. On the **Class View** explorer pane, in the Macros IDE, double-click the **EnvironmentEvents** node to display it as an **EnvironmentEvents** tab
>    and a drop-down menu on the macro editor pane.
> 2. From the **EnvironmentEvents** drop-down menu, select an events type, such as **TaskListEvents**. The **Declarations** combo box is now populated
>    with the available **Task List** events.
> 3. On the **Declarations** drop-down menu, select an event, such as **TaskAdded**, to add its event procedure to the module.
>
> The event is inserted into your macro and you can now add code to the event procedure.

Otherwise, the event handler isn't called at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a Visual Studio macro, something like this:

```
Dim WithEvents MyBuildEvents as BuildEvents

Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildBegin(ByVal Scope As EnvDTE.vsBuildScope, ByVal Action As EnvDTE.vsBuildAction) Handles MyBuildEvents.OnBuildBegin
    OpenBuildOrderOutputPane()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenBuildOrderOutputPane()
    Dim window As Window = DTE.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput) ' Get Output Window
    Dim output As OutputWindow = CType(window.Object, OutputWindow)
    For Each pane As OutputWindowPane In output.OutputWindowPanes ' Browse panes
        If (pane.Guid = "{2032B126-7C8D-48AD-8026-0E0348004FC0}") Then ' Build Order guid
            pane.Activate()
        End If
    Next
    window.Activate()
End Sub
```

You need to paste this code in MyMacros, EnvironmentEvents module.

Comment: had to modify your answer in order to get it going.

Comment: Maybe because you're running off VS 2005. This change is not needed on VS 2010 (there is some auto generated code that does it)

Comment: yep. With VS2005, I **have to** create the build event handler as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b27f9kz(v=vs.80).aspx They rely on the generated code, otherwise the handlers aren't getting called...